# Showing that to any point on a curve there exists a number $ m \in \mathbb{Q} $ so that $(x,y)=(m^2-1,m^3-m)$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I have a question here, for which I don't have an idea how to prove it ..

I want to show that to any rational point $ (x,y) \in \mathbb{ Q}^2 $ on a curve

$$ C:= \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | y^2=x^2+x^3 \} \subset \mathbb{R}^2 $$

there exists a number $m \in \mathbb{Q} $ so that 
$$ (x,y)= (m^2-1,m^3-m) $$

very thankful for any help!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: For $(0,0)$, take $m=1$. If $(x,y)$ is a rational point with $x\neq 0$, let $m=\frac y x$ and solve for $x$ and $y$, noting that $\left(\frac yx\right)^2=x+1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x=0$, then $y=0$ and we can take $m=0$. Otherwise, if $x,y$ are rational, then so is $m=y/x$. Then $y^2=x^2+x^3$ gives $m^2=1+x$, or $x=m^2-1$. Hence $y=mx=m^3-m$.